# Why/How does setting `rowspan` on <td> seems giving an unexpected layout in HTML table?

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Receipt</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">item</td>
            <td rowspan="2">price</td>
            <td rowspan="2">quantity</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>book</td>
            <td>17.99</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>pencil</td>
            <td>2.99</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">subTotal:</td>
            <td>26.96</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">tax:</td>
            <td>2.40</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">total:</td>
            <td>29.36</td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

I have the above HTML where I want to use `rowspan` to control my first row's height, but it seems to give me a very weird layout where content of my 2nd  is wrapped up to the first row. (see image).[table layouot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h9BX.png)

Does anyone know why? And what's my alternative here?

I have try validating my HTML format online to see if I messed up any format. And most of them said
`A table row was 6 columns wide and exceeded the column count established by the first row (3).`. I'm not sure whether it is related to that or another thing which I am also very confused.

I generated the HTML with Freemaker template with Java.

---

## update

[this layout was what I looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhOfp.png)

Currently,

- a. the wrapping problem is solved by adding an empty `<tr></tr>` after the 1st row;
- b. however, the height of the 1st row is not effective with the `rowspan="2"` so I resorted to `css` `height="2em"` on `<tr>`.

Comment: rowspan and colspan are semantic descriptions of the table cell. They are not there to be used for setting heights and widths. That's what CSS is for.

Answer (score 0):

check this out is this what you asking for, if yus then just change rowspan to 1 and remove colspan from everywhere.{And you can style to look better (i just used for better looking u can avoid if u want)}
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d96Bl.png

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. The following was actually what I look for link --- I have overcome the problem of 2nd row being wrapped by adding an empty` <tr></tr>` after the 1st row. But the height is still ineffective with rowspan. I might have been misunderstanding the rules of `<table>` . Currently using css solves the height problem. But somehow imperfect in my opinion. because I kind of expect `rowspan` to work the way I expected until I get some more sense spoken into me on that matter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- You have set rowspan="2" for the first three cells in the first row.
- This means that these cells should span two rows vertically.
- So the second row should be empty
- but the height issue will not be solved by this method.
- To control the height of the first row without using rowspan, you can apply CSS styling.

  ```
  <style>        
   .first-row {
       height: 60px;
   }
  </style>
  ```
- Add class="first-row" to your first row, adjust the height accordingly by changing the 60px;

For more clarification :
For example if you have 3 cells in a row and you have added rowspan="2" for first 2 cells in first row,
second row should contain only one cell.

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td  rowspan="2">Heading 1 </td>
    <td  rowspan="2">Heading 2</td>
    <td>Heading 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sub Heading</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see. That explains why adding an extra empty row works. Thanks!